# cocoa garbage collection doesnt work?

Tags: cocoa, garbage-collection

I have enabled garbage collection in my Cocoa application.
[image]

Why does my application still use a lot of memory. Actually, its not just using a lot of memory, if I leave it running for a few hours it will take up a few gigabytes, which is out of control.
[image]

Is there something special that I need to do to make this work?

Comment: In the screenshot - you have enabled garbage collection for "debug" configuration. Are you sure you're not profiling the app compiled with "release" configuration?

Comment: Garbage collection doesn't mean you can't have memory leaks. Instruments should be able to show you which objects are still alive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but there are a couple of ways this can happen:

1. You might have zombies enabled on the Allocations instrument or in your target's environment. Check both and make sure zombies are turned off.
2. You might be abandoning memory (holding onto objects, even ones you never use after a certain point, and never letting go of them). This is especially easy if you add objects to some sort of cache and never actually purge any from it. (`imageNamed:` does this, so beware if you're loading a lot of images that way.) Use heapshots to see what objects are piling up, and then look into their histories to see where they were created. Also use the Object Graph instrument to see what's keeping them alive.

Also, you are straight-up leaking objects (probably CF objects, which are not collectable by default). Select the Leaks instrument to see what it has to say.

Comment: I'm using an "IKImageView" to display a new image every few seconds. The image is loaded into an NSImage with "[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:LocalTempImageStorage]" and converted to a "CGImageRef" with some CoreGrahics functions. From what you are saying this sounds like a possible culprit. What are my alternatives?

Comment: Converted with Core Graphics functions, you say? NSImage actually has a method to create a CGImage; you might consider using that instead. That's still just wild guessing at the cause of the problem, though; Instruments will tell you exactly what you are leaking and where you created it.